# Sorting in descending order

Tags: python

I am sorting out text files, which contain a name and a score from a quiz.
They look something like this:

```
Tom,10
Tom,6
Tom,2
Geoff,2
Geoff,4
Geoff,9
```

I have got a problem. I had this program working recently, but now it just wont work and I'm struggling to see why. The program is this:

```
def highscore1():
    n = 0
    fo = open("class1.txt" , "r")
    ab = fo.readlines()
    y = len(ab)
    list1 = []
    for y in range(0,y):
        a = ab.pop()
        number = a.split(",")
        b = number.pop()
        b = int(b)
        list1.extend([(number,b)])
        list1.sort(key=lambda list1: list1[1], reverse = True)
     print(list1)

highscore1()
```

The program sorts out the scores in descending order. But i keep getting a problem like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python Coursework/ab.py", line 16, in <module>
    highscore1()
  File "G:/Python Coursework/ab.py", line 11, in highscore1
    b = int(b)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Why am i getting this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You really should choose more describing variables when writing code. It will make it easier for others to read and understand your code, and it will also help yourself understand it when you have left it for a few weeks and come back to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your function is very Inefficient , secondly the reason of your error is that you didn't strip your lines thus after splitting the lines you'll have a newline `\n` in your list! and hence you get the following error :

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

To get rid of this error you can `strip` your lines. So (as a more efficient way) you can just do the following :

```
sorted([line.strip().split(',') for line in open("class1.txt")],key=lambda x :x[1],reverse = True)
```

Comment: "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" emerges when trying this code.

Comment: @tempaah but it works fine for me! are you sure about the content of your file!

Comment: Yes, there was a problem with my input file, that I couldnt see. Thank you for the help! @Kasra AD

Comment: the content of the text file?

Comment: @tempaah yes, the input file that you get error with!

Comment: `Tom,3
South,5
James,0
Tom,0
Tom,7
South,0
South,7
James,5
James,10`

Comment: @tempaah did you tried my code correctly? you just need to do that instead of whole of your code!

Comment: What do i need to 'print' because it is blank when i run the code?

Answer (score 0):

No issue to following one:-

`\n` is present in list of lines. Just do strip().

In your code:  `a = ab.pop().strip()`

---

There might be blank line in your input file at the end. Can just print the `ab` list to check.

[image]

---

Just re write your code::

code:

```
def highscore1():
    p = '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/newoneserial.txt'    
    with open(p ,"r")as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        result = []
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            try:
                name, score = line.split(",")
            except ValueError:
                continue
            try:
                score = int(score)
            except ValueError:
                continue

            result.append((name,score))

        result.sort(key=lambda result: result[1], reverse = True)

        print(result)

highscore1()
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 24.py 
[('Tom', 10), ('Geoff', 9), ('Tom', 6), ('Geoff', 4), ('Tom', 2), ('Geoff', 2)]
```

Comment: I tried this, but i still get a error.                                                         
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: hi, There is blank line in your input file. can just print the ab list to check?

Comment: I tried to print the ab list, But the same error from before still emerges.

Comment: can email me input file on vivekbsable@gmail.com or shear on skype vivek.igp ??

Comment: Input file email sent.

Comment: there is blank line at the end of class1.txt file, just remove last line and check again.. replied on gmail

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing and contains a number of errors. Here's a rewrite that I think accomplished what you're trying to do very succinctly. It will also ignore blank lines and lines without a comma in them.

```
def highscore1():
    with open("class1.txt") as fo:
        ab = fo.readlines()
    list1 = [(name, int(number)) for name, number in (pair.split(',')
                                    for pair in ab if ',' in pair)]
    list1.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse = True)
    print(list1)

highscore1()
```

Output:

```
[('Tom', 10), ('Geoff', 9), ('Tom', 6), ('Geoff', 4), ('Tom', 2), ('Geoff', 2)]
```

Comment: **File "G:\Python Coursework\r.py", line 7, in highscore1
    name, number = pair.split(",")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack** emerges.

Comment: Looks like the `class1.txt` file either has a line in it without two values separated by a `,` character (which might be a blank line at the end). You can always add a `print(pair)` before the `pair.split()` and see what the data is that's causing the problem.